# Facebook chatbox doesn't reload between pages

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, html5-history

I observed this feature in Facebook, that when you have a chat box opened at the bottom right, and you go to another page, say, your friend's profile, or some photo collection page within Facebook, the chat box doesn't reload, it remains where it is (as if in a separate layer on top of the background page).

So naturally, I thought that Facebook isn't reloading the page per se, it is using `history.pushstate` and related functions to load the content asynchronously, and changing the URL dynamically (Firebug confirmed it, if you click on one of your friend's name and is taken to your friend's profile page, it is actually a `GET` request that is getting fired). So since there isn't exactly any page loading, the chatbox can just lay idle, as it is.

However, `pushstate` isn't supported by `IE` prior to version 10. Still, it works just fine in `IE9` as well. So can anyone tell me how are they doing it? Are they using the `history` API at all, or something different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a great question with a simply answer. I'm not sure about Facebook, but this should help you - [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js)

> History.js gracefully supports the HTML5 History/State APIs (pushState, replaceState, onPopState) in all browsers. Including continued support for data, titles, replaceState. Supports jQuery, MooTools and Prototype. For HTML5 browsers this means that you can modify the URL directly, without needing to use hashes anymore. For HTML4 browsers it will revert back to using the old onhashchange functionality.

Comment: Yeah I know this was coming. But the problem is that it says for HTML4 browsers, it relies on `onHashChange` function. However, for IE89, I am clearly seeing that there are multiple cases where not only the hash is changed, but path is changed as well.In these cases also, IE9 doesn't reload the page (and thus the chat box stays). only dynamically changes the URL..

Comment: Okay okay, I got it, all the new path fragmented and other stuff are added after the hash sign, meaning that they all are part of the hash. Right?

Comment: Right, I did not tested it, but it seems to be like this. The best example is the mobile version of Facebook (https://m.facebook.com/) which includes a hash system in it.

Comment: @Alexis'ZeNy'Bize is right, on HTML5 it uses the State API, and on HTML4, JS manipulation of the hash. (reimplementation of State API ;))

Comment: I used a third party chat tool (jivochat.com) to add real-time chat support to my website (userbob.com). Somehow the jivochat window usually stays visible even when you navigate to different pages on my site. I don't get how that works, but it's awesome. Anyone know how that is done?   It doesn't seem to work 100% of the time.   Sometimes the window closes and redisplays.