# PopUp back button in mobile browser

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, browser

Q: In my project i have a requirement that when a user clip on a card, a pop up should open with details. Later if user hits back button, the pop up should close and stay at the same place.

I've dived into all the blogs and information in google regarding this and found that it is an exception for pop ups.

I would like to know is there any way to do using angularJS or any other scripting??

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597021/facebook-chatbox-doesnt-reload-between-pages